# 500 internal server error while wordpress menu updating

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

*Once I've try to edit my navigation menu on the `Wordpress site`, It shows `500 internal server error`. I have a custom link on my main-menu, now I need to edit the `URL` of the link.*

*When I click `Save Menu` it show me above error. And the error page is following as:*

[image: Wordpress admin panel menu page]

*I just want to change the `link(URL)` on the `Inspections`.*

*Is there any possible way to do that directly in the database.*

*Please help me,*

Comment: can you show the URL?

Comment: Show in your error logs!

Comment: Try to clean your browsers (and WP cache if used) cache. Seems to be that the modified menu item is cached...

Comment: Another possible way is delete the menu item and create it again.
In WP are menu items stored in the wp_post table (row post_type=nav_menu_item).